# How to stop multiple threads in a Client-Server scenario? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im trying to create a chat application in C#. As a classic Client-server model, when server socket accepts a new client, a new thread is initiated with a "client handler" role. My question is, is there a correct way of terminating these "client handler" threads, when server is shutdown by a button click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close all the sockets in the client list, so making all the read calls return early with an error/exception, so alowing them to all clean up and exit and then wait for them all to terminate.
I would probably just call Environment.Exit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way as far as I know is calling `socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);` on each client socket. This will send any remaining data and inform the client that you're shutting down. The client *should* respond with shutting down their send channel, causing you to receive a message of 0 bytes. At that point you can close the socket.

I hardly see anyone use the `Shutdown` method though nor do they wait for the disconnect response (the 0 bytes) from the client, probably because it delays shutdown when one of the clients does not respond to the shutdown.

See the [Winsock FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html#howclose) for more information - not a .NET resource but the `Socket` class isn't that far off.